# Retaining series order with one to many SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm working on a project where I need to store individual issues and titles in such a way that preserves their order in a series.

```
--------------------------------------
| id | title | series_id (foreign key)|
--------------------------------------
```

is how I'd usually go about it but that wouldn't retain the proper order. Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this, keeping in mind that it will need to be done for several different series of varying lengths? The rest of the project does require a relational database so sadly they can't just be stored as a JSON file.

EDIT: ideally it should take a set of titles like "foo", "bar","this","that" and associate them with a series called "some words" so that they can be returned in that order when a user request information on "some words"

Comment: please data sample and expected result sample

Comment: ideally it should take a set of titles like "foo", "bar","this","that" and associate them with a series called "some words" so that they can be returned in that order when a user request information on "some words"

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: This is super early in the project, Postgresql is what I'd like to use but MySQL is still an option.

Comment: Provided `id` is an ascending identity column, you'd have an order: later inserted records come after earlier inserted ones. If you don't want to rely on IDs being issued in ascending order, you'd have to add a column for this you fill yourself.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, should have been clearer. There's one table for all individual issues and another table of the series titles so relying on issue ids isn't going to work. If I'm understanding your suggestion I'd need to have a separate column on the issues that used a foreign key of the series and another with the rank value?

Comment: The table you are showing in your request contains the issues and it has an ID. So if for a series 123 I find two entries in the table `id=88 title = 'something'` and `id=789 title = 'something else'`, then issue 88 comes before issue 789, because the number is smaller.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner unfortunately there's really no way to ensure that users enter items in an order that would guarantee that issue ids would be a reliable method. Appreciate the thought though.

Comment: Okay then instead of using the ID, you'd add a column `issue_number` or `sort_key` or whatever name you like and use this to get an order. And you can always change it. So if you have issues #1 and #2 for series 123 and want to insert an issue between the two, you'd update #2 to #3 and then insert the new one with #2.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner cool, thanks. I feel like an idiot for not thinking of it earlier. Reasons to not code after being up for 30 hours I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ThorstsonKettner for pointing me in the right direction and apologies for missing the simple answer.

> "...you'd add a column issue_number or sort_key or whatever name you like and use this to get an order. And you can always change it. So if you have issues #1 and #2 for series 123 and want to insert an issue between the two, you'd update #2 to #3 and then insert the new one with #2"